# Are Iraqi Chaldean (Suraye) related to the Chaldean mentioned in old testament?

Tags: church-history

I am looking for a reliable resource about the history of the christian Chaldean in Iraq and where the name "Suraya" come from.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. Can you provide a little more background on what group you're talking about, and its relation to the name "Suraya" (or is it Suraye as in the title)? What have you found out about them so far? What are you having trouble finding out about them? See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Chaldeans are catholic Christians who live in Iraq. Many immigrated to the USA. I read that the Christian faith came from Syria to Iraq hence the name "Suraya" but there is no evidence to this claim. Chaldean have there own language "Surath" and I was not able to find out the origin of this language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Questions about the history of the people group could perhaps be asked at [history.se]. See Wikipedia for info about the [Surat language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koy_Sanjaq_Syriac_language).

Comment: @curiousdannii You may be right. However, I concurrently answered it because it is about a religious community originating in the Middle East, and possibly about its traditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruce Feiler says, in *[Where God Was Born](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060574879)*, page 199-200, the Chaldeans of the Old Testament were an Arabic tribe that migrated northward into central Mesopotamia in about the ninth century BCE and eventually seized control of the kingdom, forming what became known as the neo-Babylonian Empire.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaldean_Christians) says the modern Chaldean Catholics are in fact Assyrians, originally from northern Iraq, northeast Syria, northwest Iran and southeast Turkey, an area that does not overlap well with the more southern homeland of the Old Testament Chaldeans.  Rome initially named the new diocese, formed by those Assyrians who broke from The Assyrian Church of the East and entered communion with the Roman Catholic Church, the Church of Assyria and Mosul.  Some 128 years later, in 1681, this was changed to The Chaldean Catholic Church, despite none of its adherents having hitherto used the name 'Chaldean' to describe themselves or their church.

In conclusion, the 'Iraqi Chaldeans' are not ethnically related to the ancient Chaldean people. The name 'Chaldeans' was chosen by the Catholic Church in Rome, although there was no precedent to support this usage.

Comment: I can now understand the history behind it and I have resources to get more details. It is confusing that they chose the name “Chaldean” for this group and even used the same spelling of the old testament. Thank you for your help.